# how to test .dll on Linux

Tags: linux, dll, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

I am a Linux user, but on my work I have a new project that is on C++. I have to generate a dynamic library from that project and test if everything work, to send it to a mate.

My problem is that a requisite of the project is that the dynamic library must be a dll, because the majority members of the projects use Windows. Morever, I dont know how to test the dynamic library because all I have read is that the dll can not be used on Linux OS, so  I dont know how to test it before send it to my mates.

I have read that are some tools to generate the dll on Linux, but I want to test the library before send it. To test it I want to code a simple cpp program on Linux that used the dll to see if the inputs and outputs are as supposed they have to be. Are there any way to test the dll on Linux to see if everything works correctly?

Thanks